# Linux Serial Port: missing data on input

Tags: c++, linux, arduino, serial-port, uart

```
    #include <fcntl.h>   
    #include <termios.h> 
    #include <unistd.h>  
    #include <errno.h>   
    #include <cerrno>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <ctime>

    using namespace std;
    typedef struct termios ComSet;

    int main()
    {
    int acm=-1;                                   
    acm=open("/dev/ttyACM0",O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    if(acm == -1)
    {
    cout<<"Error Opening ttyACM0"<<endl;
    exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
    cout<<"Preparing ttyACM0..."<<endl;
    ComSet SerialSettings;
    tcgetattr(acm, &SerialSettings);
    cfsetispeed(&SerialSettings,B9600);
    cfsetospeed(&SerialSettings,B9600);

 /* 8N1 Mode */
    SerialSettings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;   
    SerialSettings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;   
    SerialSettings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;   
    SerialSettings.c_cflag |=  CS8;     

    SerialSettings.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;       
    SerialSettings.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL; 


    SerialSettings.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);          
    SerialSettings.c_iflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);  
    SerialSettings.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;                           

 /* Setting Time outs */
    SerialSettings.c_cc[VMIN]  = 10;     /* Read at least 10 characters */
    SerialSettings.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;     /* Wait indefinetly   */

    if((tcsetattr(acm,TCSANOW,&SerialSettings)) != 0)   
    {
        cout<< " ERROR ! in Setting attributes"<<endl;

    }
    else
    {
        cout<< "=======ttyACM0 Setting====="<<endl;
        cout<<"BaudRate = 9600 StopBits = 1 Parity = none"<<endl;
        cout<<"Reading ttyACM0... "<<endl;
        char read_buffer[1024];                                
        bzero(read_buffer,1024);
        int read_bytes=0;                                      
        while(1)
         {
                tcflush(acm, TCIFLUSH);                        
                read_bytes=read(acm,&read_buffer,1024);        
                if(read_bytes>0)
                {
                    cout<<read_buffer;
                    bzero(read_buffer,1024);
                }

         }
    }



  close(acm); /* Close the serial port */

}

return 0;
}
```

for some reason code its not working properly i m trying to read from an arduino as it was working properly earlier its giving me grabled output 
such as

lo World !
Hello World !
ello World !
llo World !
llo World !

one thing that changed was

there is one extra new line in terminal output this is using cat /dev/ttyAMC0

Hello World !

Hello World !

Hello World !

Hello World !

Hello World !

i want to read line by line and as it was sent by the arduino to terminal

Comment: Please reformat the text in your question for clarity. What output were you getting, then what did you change, and what was the resulting output? What output do you want, exactly? Punctuation would also help. Otherwise, welcome to the StackOverflow community!

Comment: what do you mean by reformat ??

Comment: I mean, it's hard to understand what you are asking in English. I understand that you want to read one line at a time, but are you currently getting the output like "lo World ! Hello World ! ello" ? Or are you getting the output you want, but with an extra new line on each line?

Comment: i m getting the output as lo World ! Hello World ! ello using my program  the other one is using cat command cat /dev/ttyAMC0 which has an extra new line

Answer (score 2):

When you get garbled output like `lo World ! Hello World ! ello World !` then that usually indicates that your clock speed (baud rate) isn't matched. Make sure your Arduino is writing at a speed of 9600 baud.

Additionally, when the Arduino outputs characters, it puts them in a hardware buffer. The `read()` function takes the number of bytes you specify out of that buffer- in this case 1024. But you probably don't want to read 1024 bytes every time. Instead, I think you should read until you reach a newline character. See if there is a `readline()` function in the library you are using.

The Linux `cat` command is reading correctly, but the command itself adds an extra newline at the end.

Comment: arduino baud rate is correct and the settings are also correct checked it already

Comment: In that case, try seeing if there is a `readline()` function available. Also, look carefully at your Arduino code to make sure it is sending newline characters - the combination of the two characters `\r\n` is usually considered a newline